# instagram profile photo not saving / working?

Tags: instagram

I've uploaded a basic photo to use as my profile photo it is 180x180, I click "edit profile" I select the image from my iPhone, it show's the image in the circle view, I click "done", the profile is refreshed but then there is no profile image!

Do I have to do something else? I have tried logging in and out, and have also edited my profile information to make sure it is saving when clicking done.

Any help would be great

Comment: PNG's are accepted when first uploading you get to see the preview int he rounded circle view but as soon as you save the image is no longer rendered. .jpg worked for me

Answer (score 19):

USE image in JPEG format, it'll work!!!

Comment: Almost 4 years later and you STILL have to use JPEGs... crazy.